# bar chart with vertical scrollbar in (highstock/highchart)

Tags: highcharts, scrollbar

As you can see on the link given below  horizontal scrollbar for x-axis. In my case i need a bar chart i.e change the 'type' of chart to 'bar' but then the horizontal scrollbar for x-axis here becomes a bit confusing. Is there any option to make this scrollbar vertical in highcharts or highstocks keeping its functionality of scrolling x-axis intact.

http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/fj6d2

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type:'bar'

    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
        min: 6
    },

    legend: {
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        y: 100,
        align: 'right'
    },

    scrollbar: {
        enabled: true
    },

    series: [{
        data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
    }]
});
```

EDIT: http://jsfiddle.net/fj6d2/2226/ working example

Comment: Your jsFiddle doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It is related with fact that bar chart is inverted chart. Highstock doens't support this options, but vertical scrollbar is planned:

http://highcharts.uservoice.com/forums/55896-general?query=scrollbar